# How is this Scala stream using 16 threads?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, stream, lazy-evaluation

I’ve been experimenting using streams to generate prime numbers in Scala, and somehow it looks like the streams are running in parallel.

At first I was running into size limitations before it could really run for a long time, but now that I’ve changed it over to SafeLong and gotten rid of anything holding a head it’s been generating the primes up to 100,000,000 for the past 10-20 minutes (pretty slow, yeah, but that’s not the point).

Thing is, now that it can run for a while, I noticed that my CPU was sitting around 70% usage. That’s odd, so I checked task manager and that 70% is almost entirely the Java platform, and it’s evenly distributed across all 16 threads.

Here's the code:

```scala
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}

import spire.math.SafeLong
import spire.implicits._

object PrimesTester {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val max: SafeLong = 100000000

    println("Grabbing stream...")
    def primes: Stream[SafeLong] = getPrimesLazy(max)
    println("Done.")

    println("Opening file...")
    val oFile = new PrintWriter(new File(s"lazyPrimes_$max.txt"))
    println("Done.")

    println("Generating and saving...")
    for(p <- primes){
      oFile.println(p)
    }
    oFile.close()
    println("Done.")
  }

  def getPrimesLazy(max: SafeLong): Stream[SafeLong] = {
    //Generate all relevant odd numbers
    def odds: Stream[SafeLong] = Stream.iterate(3: SafeLong)(_ + 2).takeWhile(n => n*n <= max)

    //Generate all composite numbers in the range
    def composites: Stream[SafeLong] = odds.flatMap{ n =>
      Stream.iterate(n * n)(_ + 2 * n).takeWhile(_ <= max)
    }

    //Take all composite numbers out of the range
    2 #:: Stream.iterate(3: SafeLong)(_ + 2).takeWhile(_ <= max).diff(composites)
  }
}
```

I’m pretty sure streams are sequential, and I’ve only ever seen parallel collections behave like that.

This has me extremely curious, because working from my understanding of streams this shouldn’t happen. But here we are. Does anyone know what’s going on?

EDIT: Here's the thread dump after running for about an hour:

```
"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at spire.math.SafeLong$.apply(SafeLong.scala:211)
      at spire.math.SafeLongIsCRing.fromInt(SafeLong.scala:526)
      at spire.math.SafeLongIsCRing.fromInt$(SafeLong.scala:526)
      at spire.math.SafeLongInstances$SafeLongAlgebra$.fromInt(SafeLong.scala:509)
      at spire.math.SafeLongInstances$SafeLongAlgebra$.fromInt(SafeLong.scala:509)
      at spire.syntax.LiteralIntMultiplicativeSemigroupOps$.$times$extension(Ops.scala:189)
      at misc.PrimesTester$.$anonfun$getPrimesLazy$4(PrimesTester.scala:34)
      at misc.PrimesTester$$$Lambda$14.1902260856.apply(Unknown Source:-1)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$.$anonfun$iterate$1(Stream.scala:1207)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$$Lambda$19.2082351774.apply(Unknown Source:-1)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1171)
      - locked <0x52d> (a scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1161)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.$anonfun$takeWhile$1(Stream.scala:880)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$Lambda$10.641853239.apply(Unknown Source:-1)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1171)
      - locked <0x52e> (a scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1161)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.$anonfun$append$1(Stream.scala:255)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$Lambda$20.262366552.apply(Unknown Source:-1)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1171)
      - locked <0x52f> (a scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1161)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:534)
      at scala.collection.SeqLike.occCounts(SeqLike.scala:500)
      at scala.collection.SeqLike.diff(SeqLike.scala:455)
      at scala.collection.SeqLike.diff$(SeqLike.scala:454)
      at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.diff(Seq.scala:45)
      at misc.PrimesTester$.$anonfun$getPrimesLazy$6(PrimesTester.scala:38)
      at misc.PrimesTester$$$Lambda$5.1885996206.apply(Unknown Source:-1)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1171)
      - locked <0x52a> (a scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1161)
      at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:534)
      at misc.PrimesTester$.main(PrimesTester.scala:21)
      at misc.PrimesTester.main(PrimesTester.scala:-1)

"Finalizer@1318" daemon prio=8 tid=0x3 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
      at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler@1319" daemon prio=10 tid=0x2 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
      at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)

"Attach Listener@1316" daemon prio=5 tid=0x5 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher@1317" daemon prio=9 tid=0x4 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

Comment: How about taking a thread dump? That should answer the question.

Comment: I am thinking its OS/CPU level optimization to make full use of all CPU power.

Comment: Many JVMs have garbage collectors that are concurrent, parallel, or both. Many JVMs have JIT compilers that are concurrent, parallel, or both. Many JVMs have I/O subsystems that are concurrent, parallel, or both. It could be any or none of these reasons.

Comment: You can print `Thread.getAllStackTraces.keySet()` or schedule some thread to print it every N seconds to see what threads are created by your application.

Comment: @DonBranson I've added the thread dump to the post.
I'll also try setting up a thread to log it later today, and I'll post it here when I do.

Comment: There are only 5 threads, including one in main. So, your code uses only 1 thread.